# Do Mock objects get reset for each test?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm using the [Mockito framework](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html) to create Mock objects in my JUnit tests.  Each mock knows what methods have been called on it, so during my tests I can write

```
verify(myMock, atLeastOnce()).myMethod();
```

I am wondering if this internal mock knowledge of what it has called will persist across my tests?  If it does persist, then I could be getting false positives when using the same `verify` method in two tests.

A code example

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmrActivitiesImplTest {
    
    @Mock private MyClass myMock;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        when(myMock.myMethod()).thenReturn("hello");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // ..some logic
        verify(myMock, atLeastOnce()).myMethod();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        // ..some other logic
        verify(myMock, atLeastOnce()).myMethod();
    }  
}
```

Mock state is persisted - test2 will pass regardless, since test1's verify method passed

Mock state is reset - test2 will fail if myMock.myMethod() isn't called

Comment: If I'm not wrong, setup is called once, before all tests... so yes, all your tests are using the same mock object. You'd need to create that object at the beginning of each test method

Comment: Actually, the @Before annotation will call setup() before each test case, not just once before all the tests.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

JUnit creates a new instance of test class each time it runs a new test method and runs `@Before` method each time it creates a new test class. You can easily test it:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    System.out.println("setup");
    when(myMock.myMethod()).thenReturn("hello");
}
```

And `MockitoJUnitRunner` will create a new `MyMock` mock instance for every test method.

Comment: This is correct. **JUnit** designers wanted test isolation between test methods, so it creates a new instance of the test class to run each test method. Note that **TestNG** creator took a different way, and chose isolation per test class, that means there is no isolation between test methods of a TestNG test. Hence instance mocks might need to be reseted between each test method.

Comment: And this is a big problem when using singletons, because the mocks only will be correct for the first test...

Comment: Have you found any place where this is documented?  I have known this to be true for a while but after having someone ask I have been searching and can't seem to find it in the doc anywhere.

Comment: @dsingleton The nearest think I have found is docs about the introduction of the `reset` method but that is mainly aimed to be used by container-injected mocks: https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17 and https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 21):

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class sandbox {

    @Mock
    private MyClass myMock;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        when(myMock.myMethod()).thenReturn("hello");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        myMock.myMethod();
        verify(myMock, times(1)).myMethod();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        myMock.myMethod();
        verify(myMock, times(1)).myMethod();
    }

}
```

This passes. If the *state* persisted then the second test would fail. If you debug it you would see that you get a new instance of the mocked object for each test.

Comment: Yes, agree, if @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) is used, new mocks will be injected.

Answer (score 1):

If you just initialize the Mock objects in your `setup`, then inside each test you can provide different functionality.  You can initialize it once and change how they act/expect per test after that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this quote from [JUnit Jupiter 5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle):

> In order to allow individual test methods to be executed in isolation and to avoid unexpected side effects due to mutable test instance state, JUnit creates a new instance of each test class before executing each test method (see Definitions). This "per-method" test instance lifecycle is the default behavior in JUnit Jupiter and is analogous to all previous versions of JUnit.

Of course you can configure to make the life-cycle as class level, by doing:

> If you would prefer that JUnit Jupiter execute all test methods on the same test instance, annotate your test class with @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS). When using this mode, a new test instance will be created once per test class. Thus, if your test methods rely on state stored in instance variables, you may need to reset that state in @BeforeEach or @AfterEach methods.