# Mockito when not returning expected value in different test methods

Tags: junit, mockito

I have two test methods where the method call should return different objects in the methods calls of each test method.

Mocked call -

Test Method 1 -
when(service.getCustomer(ArgumentMatchers.any(Customer.class))).thenAnswer(invocation -> Arrays.asList(customer1));

Test Method 2 -
when(service.getCustomer(ArgumentMatchers.any(Customer.class))).thenAnswer(invocation -> Arrays.asList(customer2));

service.getCustomer(Customer) when called in method called by test method returns same customer object every time in both test methods. Does mockito stores any cache of objects returned ?

Comment: possibly customer1 and customer2 are two different references of same object?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815940/do-mock-objects-get-reset-for-each-test